# Smooth Scrolling of horizontal div html with touch device

Tags: jquery, scroll, touch, smooth-scrolling

Trying to get a div that has a fixed height and overflow scroll to have smooth scrolling on touch devices when the user is scrolling.

I see that there are a lot of solutions out there that are used based on a click action but i want this to be a scroll action only for both left and right scrolling.

Pretty much how OSX 10.7+ works with smooth scrolling.

Here is my container that i have scrolling:

```
<div id="jobs" style="position:absolute;z-index:2;top:143px;left:15px;width:305px;height:135px;overflow:scroll;">
    <img src="images/jobs-row.png" />
</div>
```

I know that i am using inline styles this is for a demo and not for a live site where i would have the CSS in the stylesheet file.

I am using jQuery already so would prefer that or straight js.

Any direction to a solution would be great.

Comment: Was able to get this plugin to work for what i needed: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com

Comment: Just needing the touch support, and after reading the documentation, I used the kinetic library, https://github.com/davetayls/jquery.kinetic